# flltering array depending upon the models or table names in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have a resultset(array) returned from a solr search which contains different rows from different tables(models).NOW suppose my models are image,video(*there are many more*) etc and my resultset contains record from every table,so how can i **filter** in such a way that after filtering i should have different objects collected in different instance variables...

**for example**

```
    search = Sunspot.search Video ,Image do
           keywords(params["search"])
          #fulltext params[:search]
          order_by(:created_at, :desc)
       end 

####this doesnt works and fails if no video/image object is present
 @videos << search.results.first(10).select{|x| x.class.name=="Video" } if search.results.include?(Video)
   @images << search.results.first(10).select{|x| x.class.name=="Image" } if search.results.include?(Image) 

so is it possible to do that i want,,moreover is there a way to check that my array includes an object of model.
example----
search.include?(Video)
or
search.any.contains?(Video)
```

**right now i am using `kind_of?/is_a?` in my view and iterate through search result,that i dont want ,hence looking for a better solution to display the searched results**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group the result by their class, and work with the resultant hash.

```
search = Sunspot.search(Video, Image) do
  keywords(params[:search])
  # fulltext params[:search]
  order_by(:created_at, :desc)
end 

@results = search.results[10].group_by(&:class)
@videos = @results[Video]
@images = @results[Image]
```

But there's little need for the `@videos` and `@images` instance variables; In your views you can render the value at each key (or an empty collection if the value is nil) `<%= render @results.fetch(Video, []) %>` and the `_video.html.erb` partial will be rendered for each one of the video objects.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
search = Sunspot.search(Video, Image) do
  keywords(params[:search])
  # fulltext params[:search]
  order_by(:created_at, :desc)
end 

results = search.results[10].presence || []
@videos = results.select? { |result| result.is_a?(Video) }
@images = results.select? { |result| result.is_a?(Image) }
```